# OpenSSL on Windows is not loading from CA Store

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl

I have a leaf cert, intermediate cert, and a root cert.

`client.crt` contains all three, by way of `cat leaf.crt intermediate.crt root.crt > client.crt`

```bash
$ # Fails
$ openssl.exe verify client.crt
C = US, ...
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error client.crt: verification failed

$ # Passes, as expected, since it has the whole chain
$ openssl.exe verify -CAfile client.crt client.crt
client.crt: OK

$ # Add intermediate and root to stores
$ certutil.exe -addstore -f "ROOT" .\root.crt
CertUtil: -addstore command completed successfully.
$ certutil.exe -addstore -f "CA" .\intermediate.crt
CertUtil: -addstore command completed successfully.

$ # Both client.crt and leaf.crt fail to verify
$ openssl.exe verify client.crt
C = US, ...
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error client.crt: verification failed
$ openssl.exe verify leaf.crt
C = US, ...
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error leaf.crt: verification failed
```

It appears as if `openssl.exe` is not picking up the certs I install. I've also gone through and installed these through the Windows certificate manager to no avail.

How do I get `openssl` to pick up this CA chain?

Comment: (0) this is not programming or development and is (now) out of scope (1) OpenSSL never uses the Windows store (2) 'verify' on a chain file is a common error, see multiple links at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204616/why-does-openssl-verify-fail-with-a-certificate-chain-file